# how to get the current value of quantity field on single product page woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get the current value of quantity filed on single product page then compare quantity filed's value to custom filed's value.If both are same then print message and If not then Add alert box.Can you help me ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the quantity input value onblur using jQuery (or regular javascript if you prefer).

```
$("input.qty").blur(function(){
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(inputValue);
});
```

You can set your custom field value in javascript

```
var customFieldValue = <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'myfield', true); ?>
```

Then, you can compare both values and do your magic.